# Make Int round off to nearest value

Tags: swift, int, double, rounding

I've got two Int values (they have to be Ints) and I want them to round off to the nearest value when in an equation;

```
var Example = Int()
var secondExample = Int()

Example = (secondExample / 7000)
```

This equation makes the variable `Example` always round down to the lowest value. Say for example that the numbers are the following;

```
var Example = Int()
var secondExample : Int = 20000

Example = (20000 / 7000)
```

20000 / 7000 equals 2.857... But the variable `Example` displays `2`.

How can I make `Example` round off to closest number **without changing it to a Double**

Comment: I don't think you can, as integers are WHOLE numbers, you can change it to a double, round it up, then change it back... but in one go i think its impossible.

Comment: You are using the wrong data type for what you want to accomplish. I'll recommend going back to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) to understand the different data types available to you in Swift.

Comment: @Brianvandenheuvel See Martin's answer, nothing is impossible. ;)

Comment: @RappeStegarn please, see my update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For *nonnegative* integers, the following function gives
the desired result in pure integer arithmetic :

```
func divideAndRound(numerator: Int, _ denominator: Int) -> Int {
    return (2 * numerator + denominator)/(2 * denominator)
}
```

Examples:

```
print(20000.0/7000.0) // 2.85714285714286
print(divideAndRound(20000, 7000)) // 3 (rounded up)

print(10000.0/7000.0) // 1.42857142857143
print(divideAndRound(10000, 7000)) // 1 (rounded down)
```

The idea is that

```
 a   1   2 * a + b
 - + - = ---------
 b   2     2 * b
```

And here is a possible implementation for arbitrarily signed
integers which also does not overflow:

```
func divideAndRound(num: Int, _ den: Int) -> Int {
    return num / den + (num % den) / (den / 2 + den % 2)
}
```

(Based on @user3441734's updated solution, so we have a reference
cycle between our answers now :)

There is also a [`ldiv`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/ldiv.3.html) function which computes both quotient
and remainder of a division, so the last function could also be 
implemented as

```
func divideAndRound(num: Int, _ den: Int) -> Int {
    let div = ldiv(num, den)
    let div2 = ldiv(den, 2)
    return div.quot + div.rem / (div2.quot + div2.rem)
}
```

(I did not test which version is faster.)

Comment: If you use this it will be safer against overflow: `return numerator / divisor + (2 * (numerator % divisor) + ((numerator >= 0) ? 1 : -1) * abs(divisor))/(2 * divisor)` - basically just rounding on the remainder.

Comment: @user3441734 I saw it just after I posted, very nice.

Comment: Thank for rearranging 'my' formula!! I voted your answer before, I would like to do it once more :-)

Comment: Thanks (and I did the same with your answer :) The tricky part was to make the rounding work correctly with odd denominators.

Comment: @DuncanC Not often I see another Duncan floating around.  :)

Answer (score 3):

see Martin's answer! his idea is great, so i extend his solution for negative numbers

```
func divideAndRound(n: Int, _ d: Int) -> Int {
    let sn = n < 0 ? -1 : 1
    let sd = d < 0 ? -1 : 1
    let s = sn * sd
    let n = n * sn
    let d = d * sd
    return (2 * n + d)/(2 * d) * s
}

divideAndRound(1, 2) // 1
divideAndRound(1, 3) // 0
divideAndRound(-1, 2) // -1
divideAndRound(-1, 3) // 0
divideAndRound(1, -2) // -1
divideAndRound(1, -3) // 0
```

the only trouble is that (2 * n + d) can overflow and code will crash.

**UPDATE!** with help of mathematics for children

```
func divr(a: Int, _ b: Int)->Int {
    return (a % b) * 2 / b  + a / b
}
```

**it should work for any Int :-) except 0 denominator**.

Comment: I just tested the update and it works, nice algorithm.

Comment: Good idea, but actually `(a % b) * 2` *can* overflow, try `divideAndRound(9223372036854775643, 9223372036854775783)` :)

Comment: I think you are wrong. If 0 <= a < b then a / b = 0 but a % b = a. You can test it with the above example. I admit that it might be a border case. It can be solved (see my update which is based on your update :)

Comment: @MartinR i deleted my stupid note :-), I am takin a bath .... Will check it in an hour. Thank you in advance!