# Round Integer Numbers in Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to round the integer number to the nearest hundredth for currency purposes, How is it possible in Swift?

Example: 1397968 becomes 1397900

Comment: How would you do it in another language? And what did you try already?

Comment: Is `/ 100 * 100` sufficient?

Comment: if that is really what you want to do then vadian's comment does the magic. are we missing something?

Comment: Huh! this simple ya? Thank you @vadian

Comment: The *nearest* multiple of 100 would be 1398000, not 1397900.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round Double to closest 10 (Swift)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922406/round-double-to-closest-10-swift)

Comment: @shallowThought: That is very close, but here the input is an *integer* which simplifies things.

Comment: @Martin R: true. Also I am enjoying the rounding battle :-)

Comment: Thanks @MartinR for the answer, i just want to know the logic of rounding, and all is correct!

Comment: **ALWAYS USE [`NSDecimalNumber` / `Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/decimal) FOR CURRENCY!!**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to round *down* to a multiple of 100 then you can
do that with (as @vadian said in a comment):

```
let amount = 1397968
let rounded = amount/100 * 100
print(rounded) // 1397900
```

This works because integer division *truncates* the result
towards zero: `amount/100` evaluates to `13979`, and multiplying
by 100 again gives `1397900`.

But you asked for the *nearest* multiple of 100 for a given integer,
and that can be done with a small modification:

```
let amount = 1397968
let rounded = (amount + 50)/100 * 100
print(rounded) // 1398000
```

for *nonnegative* integers. If you have both positive and negative
values then [@shallowThought's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40951339/1187415) is probably the easiest
way to go. But it *can* be done with pure integer arithmetic as well
(using the approach from [Make Int round off to nearest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377244/make-int-round-off-to-nearest-value)):

```
func roundToHundreds(_ value: Int) -> Int {
    return value/100 * 100 + (value % 100)/50 * 100
}

roundToHundreds(123) // 100
roundToHundreds(188) // 200

roundToHundreds(-123) // -100
roundToHundreds(-188) // -200
```

This works for the full range of `Int`:

```
roundToHundreds(Int.max) // 9223372036854775800
roundToHundreds(Int.min) // -9223372036854775800
```

Answer (score 7):

```
let value = 1397968
let rounded = Int(round(Double(value) / 100) * 100)
print(rounded)
```

-> `1398000`

Comment: This has the advantage of rounding negative values correctly as well. However, it does not work correctly with *very* large integers, e.g. 123456789012345678 rounds to 123456789012345696.

Comment: 123456789012345678 is well below Int.max. The problem is that the the mantissa of Double has only 54 bits, therefore `Double(value)` loses precision if value>2^54.

Comment: True too. Before your edit, it was Int.max though ;-)

Comment: Yes, I changed that (with Int.max your code overflows) – sorry for the confusion. Of course these are corner cases and probably not relevant in most applications. 1,234,567,890,123,456,78 would be > 1234 Trillion, and unlikely as an amount that you work with :)

Answer (score 6):

> Please refer to the post by *@Martin R* for a more detailed answer.

As *@vadian* said, you can write

```
let value = 1397968
let rounded = value / 100 * 100
```

Now you can print it

```
print(rounded) // 1397900
```

Comment: Yup this is it! Thanks, turns our so simple!