# Create smaller evenly distributed array

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

I'm trying to create a smaller array from a larger array.

I need the items in the array to be evenly distributed to match the larger array.

So for example, the larger array contains 420 items. The smaller array contains 375.

I am able to get the results I am looking for within a reasonable margin of error using the following code:

```
var smallArray = []
let smallArraySize = 375
//largeArray contains 420 items
let difference = largeArray.count - smallArraySize
let step = ceil(largeArray.count / smallArraySize)

for (index, item) in largeArray.enumerated {
  if index % Int(step) != 0 {
     smallArray.append(item)
  }
}
```

This results in a **smallArray** that has 373 items. Which achieves my requirement.

However, if the large array contains more items, for example 1020, this no longer works.

Specifically, this seems to be an issue when the **difference** is larger than the **smallArraySize**.

Using the same code on a larger number results in a **step** that is 1, so the new array is empty.

Comment: what is the nature of the content of these arrays? and why do you want to skip some information in the large array? are you trying to package them in buckets somehow with a limited size ? if so then there are multiple approaches like taking averages or medians .. etc. please elaborate on your problem

Comment: How would you want to reduce a 100 element array to e.g. 23 elements? Picking every 5th element gives 20 elements (too few), and picking every 4th element gives 25 elements (too many).

Comment: This looks more like a statistical problem than a swift problem.

Comment: @CME64 I have data corresponding with minutes across variable amounts of time. Each data point has a state (color). The design wants a "summary" of the time span and the colors that spans the width of the screen at intervals of 1 pixel.

Comment: @Marin R I realize this, that is why I want to be close (as mentioned in my post 373 is close enough to 375). I can increase the width of the data points in the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a subarray with “almost evenly distributed” elements if you  map each index from the smaller array to a suitable index of the larger array:

```
extension Array {
    func subArray(withSize n: Int) -> [Element] {
        precondition(n >= 0 && n <= count)
        return (0..<n).map { self[($0 * count + count/2)/n] }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

print(array.subArray(withSize: 1)) // [4]
print(array.subArray(withSize: 2)) // [2, 6]
print(array.subArray(withSize: 3)) // [1, 4, 6]
print(array.subArray(withSize: 4)) // [1, 3, 5, 7]
print(array.subArray(withSize: 5)) // [0, 2, 4, 5, 7]
print(array.subArray(withSize: 6)) // [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
print(array.subArray(withSize: 7)) // [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(array.subArray(withSize: 8)) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

The following illustration shows roughly how three elements are picked out of eight:

```
┌──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┐
│ 0│ 1│ 2│ 3│ 4│ 5│ 6│ 7│
└──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┘
    ⬆      ⬆      ⬆︎   
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│   0   │   1   │   2   │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Gotta luv an answer with illustrations! The way you thought of `($0 * count + count/2)/n` is magic to me (I still don't get how it works with all the integer divisions included). Anyway, I would prefer to pre-calculate `count/2` (division is slow on Intel processors as you already know). (Removed my answer to avoid any similarities)

Comment: @ielyamani: The idea is that `($0 + 0.5)*count/n = ($0 * count + count/2)/n` – the 0.5 is exactly the “half step” from your solution (which gives identical results in my few tests).

Comment: @ielyamani: Here https://stackoverflow.com/q/36377244/1187415 are some similar ideas about a rounding division in pure integer arithmetic.

Comment: Integer division is throwing me off, `count` could be odd, and then `count/2` wouldn't equal (0.5 * count). The result is the same since the goal is the same, but I don't see how yours works. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @ielyamani: Yes, `self[($0 * 2* count + count)/(2*n)]` is better, but I did not detect a difference. It probably does not matter for *this task.*

Comment: (I've just checked with `Array(1...100)` and various `smallArraySize`s. the methods yield different results. I believe because yours rounds to the nearest integer, and mine floored it)